# Algorithm to color the edges of the square of a cycle

Tags: algorithms, graphs, colorings

It is known that any power of cycle on even vertices is in [Class 1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895685900565/pdf?md5=51c8977b64ffcdc0d27eefe132a12814&pid=1-s2.0-0095895685900565-main.pdf), that is, can be edge colored in $\Delta$ colors, where $\Delta$ is its maximum degree which equals twice the power. But, I wish to know a specific algorithm to edge color the powers of cycles of even order.

Say, I have the square of a $18$ cycle. Now, this graph consists of a disjoint $18$ cycle, and two disjoint $9$cycles.  The $18$ cycle can be easily colored with $2$ colors. But, the two disjoint $9$ cycles being odd, must require $3$ colors each, which are in turn distinct from the two colors used on the $18$ cycle. This implies that the graph is not a Class 1 graph, that is requires one more color than its degree. So, is the first premise that all powers of cycles of even order are class 1 false. And, if true, what can be a general algorithm to do so for any power of a cycle? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Perhaps you can give a citation for "It is known that any power of cycle on even vertices is in Class 1"? Also, there are several different definitions of graph product. Are you using the correct one?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus though not directly, but [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895685900565/pdf?md5=51c8977b64ffcdc0d27eefe132a12814&pid=1-s2.0-0095895685900565-main.pdf) a paper that describes that all cayley graphs on an abelian group of even order is class 1

Comment: @YuvalFilmus my criterion of graph powers is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power)

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] your question to improve it, including providing background to make it useful for others.  Comments exist to help you improve your question - please don't leave information only in the comments.  Thank you!

Comment: @D.W. edted the post including the reference